# Java ServerSocket and HttpServer

Tags: java, serversocket, httpserver

I want to implement a client server communication involving decent amount of data being passed.       (~ 50MB)

Should I implement the back end using the `ServerSocket` or `HttpServer`?
What are the pointers to decide?

Thanks.

Comment: Might want to look into some frameworks for the basic stuff, e.g. [Netty](http://netty.io/) or [Ratpack](http://www.ratpack.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Mainly it depends if you want to communicate to the client using the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or you want to set up a simple TCP/IP connection and than use the another application protocol.

[Netty](http://netty.io/) simplify the implementation of both the solution, [Ratpack](http://www.ratpack.io/) focuses on HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

you give too little details about what the backend would be. Standard approaches use a Tomcat at the back (if you are in Java) or apache webserver and a REST based data exchange mechanism between the client and server.